# Special Non-linear recurrence

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, algorithms, recurrence-relations

**Problem** I have a non-linear recurrence relation given by

$$ a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3} - \sqrt{a_{n-1}.a_{n-2}+a_{n-2}.a_{n-3}+a_{n-3}.a_{n-1}}  $$

Given $ a_1, a_2 $ and $ a_3 $,I have to find the nth term of the sequence in $ O(\log n)$ time.

I know if the recurrence dependence is linear then we can solve the problem in logrithmic time (see [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/892643/115535))  but I don't know for this special case.

Actually my original problem is to find the radius of nth circle, given the radius of first 4 circles, from the figure shown below

[image: Circles]

For it I am trying to use Descartes theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem) in the form of the recurrences above.

Please suggest any approach.

Comment: In your figure, the circle $C_n$ touches $C_1,C_2,C_{n-1}$, not $C_{n-3},C_{n-2},C_{n-1}$. Does that simplify things for you?

Comment: Yeah, but still $C_n$ depends on $C_{n-1}$ non linearly. Logarithmic running time may not be possible still ?

Comment: Note further that for $n\geq5$ both $C_n$ and $C_{n-2}$ touch $C_1,C_2,C_{n-1}$. That is, you already know some solutions of your nonlinear recurrence. This should enable you to divide those out.